# CMD command to check connected USB devices

Tags: windows, command-prompt, prompt

I would like to obtain by a command prompt a list of all USB devices connected to my computer (O.S. Windows 10). I've googled to find such a command, but all results seems useless to me or worse workless. Does anybody know how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can download USBview and get all the information you need. Along with the list of devices, it will also show you the configuration of each device.

Comment: USBview is part of the debug tools for windows. You can see how to get this program here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview

Comment: Why is this accepted and -6 without any good comments?

Comment: The accepted answer is not a command. Thats why I down voted.

Comment: if the accepted answer is not something that was wanted in the first place, then it means that the question was somewhat asked  incorrectly. So i think it's better to down vote the question either. because it wanted a command but accepted a software recommendation as the answer! so the question was not asked correctly at the first place, right?

Answer (score 34):

You can use the [**wmic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmic) command:

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with mobile devices since they don't mount to be a drive.

Comment: WMIC is deprecated

Comment: what is the replacement for WMIC, Sir @KVM?

Comment: @ASPaiva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121875/what-can-i-do-about-wmic-is-deprecated

Answer (score 13):

With powershell, you can use the command :

```
Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' }
```

a simple short to use powershell from cmd and get result :

```
powershell "Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' }"
```

Comment: This worked great on my Windows 10! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use wmic command:

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get <DeviceID, VolumeName, Description, ...>
```

Drivetype 2 indicates that its a removable disk.

Comment: you have to remove spaces around  '=' to get result -> wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get *

Comment: You should have in mind, that external Hard Drives have drivetype=3 (local disk) like internal hard drives. Only USB sticks have drivetype=2.

Answer (score 2):

```
pnputil /enum-devices /connected /class USB
```

This requires Windows 10 1903 or higher. [List of possible flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax#enum-devices)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
powershell -noLogo -NoProfile "Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' -and $_.FriendlyName -match 'G27'}" | find /i "G27" >nul

if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo.Plug G27 steering wheel into USB port
) else (
  echo.ok
)
pause
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).