# What can I do about "WMIC is deprecated"?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, wmic

I've been relying on these two commands:

```
wmic memorychip get capacity        // Outputs how much RAM there is (in a convoluted manner).
wmic diskdrive get Status,Model     // Checks whether the HDDs/SSDs on the system are (supposedly) still "OK" and working.
```

Today, I casually typed "wmic" to see if I could get JSON output to the above commands. The first thing it printed, in red text, was this:

```
WMIC is deprecated.
```

I was pretty shocked by this. It's deprecated? Alright... Then I definitely should not be relying on it. What are the "modern alternatives" for those two commands, then? Do they even exist? Why do they just tell us that it's "deprecated" with zero further information?

Comment: The alternative to the command processor is PowerShell.

Comment: I asked for the alternative to WMIC -- not cmd.exe...

Comment: WMIC is the command line tool to access WMI. WMIC is deprecated. Go ahead and access WMI using PowerShell instead.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but *"[Beginning in 2012, WMIC is deprecated in favor of PowerShell cmdlets which perform equivalent CIM operations, such as get-wmiobject, invoke-wmimethod, Get-wmiobject, and gwmi.](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm)"*

Comment: How is this related to software development?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, wmic.exe is used in batch script scripting, since CMD has no builtin capability to use WMI to inspect and manage the system.

Comment: A problem with Microsoft's old command-line tools is that text encoding is a mess. Some programs output using the OEM codepage, some use the ANSI codepage, some use the current console input or output codepage, and some can do UTF-16, but usually only to a disk file (e.g. wmic.exe). I'm glad to see this ad hoc mess of tools deprecated. PowerShell, with its cmdlets and .NET, is a better command-line environment. (That said, its support for classic standard I/O is unacceptably bad. It injects itself as a middle man in pipes and redirection to files in order to transcode bytes as text.)

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned in comments, WMIC is utility that acts as interface to communication with WMI. It's not WMI itself that is being deprecated, but "just" the interface. Since Microsoft is pushing PowerShell, I believe official successor wmic would be PowerShell commandlet <s>`Get-WmiObject`. How to use this can be found on Microsoft documentation: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject)</s>

**[UPDATED]** As correctly pointed out within comment, commandlet `Get-WmiObject` may eventually sunset one day as well and thus its use may not be encouraged to have scripts future proof. Best method to stick with would be `Get-CimInstance`, which has pretty much the same syntax as `Get-WmiObject`. See Microsoft documentation: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/CimCmdlets/Get-CimInstance)

For your particular case PowerShell alternative would be the following:

> wmic memorychip get capacity

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory | Select-Object capacity
```

> wmic diskdrive get Status,Model

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_diskdrive | Select-Object status, model
```

Commands in `wmic` are usually derived from WMI class names, but it's not really a rule of thumb. With PowerShell you are accessing WMI by its real class name instead, so you may need to seek for other classes if needed.

As mentioned in comment by Bacon Bits. WMIC aliases to real WMI classes can be obtained by command:

```
wmic.exe alias list brief
```

Undisputed advantage to `PowerShell` over `wmic` is that output is an object and you can easily continue working with the output, while wmic returns a string only that you eventually need to parse for example if used inside scripts and that brings another benefit of e.g. output formatting - you can easily reformat any output for example to as you mentioned JSON, just pass your command through another pipe into commandlet `ConvertTo-Json` and you will have your expected output.

**Example:**

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_diskdrive | select status, model | ConvertTo-JSON
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "status":  "OK",
    "model":  "SAMSUNG MZNTY256HDHP-000L7"
}
```

Hope this helps

**[UPDATE 2.2.2022]**
Since this is the first link on Google for this topic that pops out, here's small update:

Microsoft officially informed about wmic being deprecated in their [WMIC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)

Microsoft page quotes:

> The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is deprecated as of Windows 10, version 21H1, and as of the 21H1 semi-annual channel release of Windows Server. This utility is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI. This deprecation applies only to the WMI command-line (WMIC) utility; Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) itself is not affected.

For the sake of future proof scripts, I would still stick with industrial CIM standard using PowerShell

Comment: Note that you can get a crosswalk of the aliases and the actual WMI class names with `wmic.exe alias list brief`.

Comment: This is not good.  I have a startnet.cmd script that is in need of wmic.exe,  Is Microsoft going to start calling startnet.ps1 in its place?  For context. startnet.cmd is script that is called when winpe boots.

Comment: @RichardMeadows I personally don't have much deep experience with winpe, yet wmic has been deprecated just recently (see my answer update). As long as your bootable winpe media contains wmic, script should work. While in future it's likely that updated winpe creation tool will be updated along with this script. I would not be much worried in here, unless you have your custom part done there as well in .cmd script, then it's worth exploring how to use powershell instead

Comment: [Here's a wayback machine link for Get-CimInstance](https://web.archive.org/web/20231212155055/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.4).