# List all connected USB devices c++ libusb/win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, libusb-1.0

Hi hope everyone is doing well!

I got a task to do and I have no idea how to complete this!

**I need to list all USB devices currently connected** and also have listeners updating if any new devices are connected or disconnected!

The language is **c++** and I'm using **Visual Studio**

I made something already however it **does not list my connected phone.**
here is the current code that I got from another post and edited a bit:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    int main()
{

    char VolumeName[MAX_PATH + 1];
    char DriveLetter[] = "A:\\";

    for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; ++count)
    { 
        DriveLetter[0] = count;
        if (GetVolumeInformation(DriveLetter, VolumeName, MAX_PATH + 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0) != FALSE)
            if (count == 'F') {
                cout << DriveLetter << "....." << VolumeName << endl;
            }

}

}
```

I have already looked at how to do it with **libusb** and I do not understand a thing! The library is in C and I do not know how to do C and I'm pretty new at c++ too Also I don't know how to add that library to my existing project.

Also tried **pololu Libusb (LIBUSBP)** however that I do not understand how to build.

Also tried **win32 API** and it's just too complicated!

If you could do this task for me I would be grateful please post the code
If someone can please just give me some good instructions.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433346/cmd-command-to-check-connected-usb-devices

Comment: WMI will expose this, but COM has something of a learning curve before you start on the specifics of WMI!