# A CMD command to list the connected devices via USB?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line-interface

I need a command to list the connected devices via USB in Windows 8 (no PowerShell, only CMD)

I can't use aditional software. I can't use a batch file. I can't use another tool. I only can use CMD to detect the connected devices. It's not important the type of devices, only need to know the port of the devices.

Comment: A WMI query via WMIC, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433346/cmd-command-to-check-connected-usb-devices

Comment: Just note, if you take the [[tag:wmic]] route, that a with `Win32_LogicalDisk`, a `drivetype` of `2`, does not mean it's USB device, just a drive which identifies as removable. Also all USB drives do not identify themselves as such, so they may not be listed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `devcon` to list the USBs:
`%WindowsSdkDir%\tools\x64\devcon.exe /find *USB*` - but you need Windows SDK installed for it to be available.

On Windows 10 you don't need the SDK and can use the `pnputil /enum-devices | findstr USB` to list the devices but this functionality isn't available on Win8.

You can also try `wmic` per @AlexK comment